# Momentjs parse wrong format date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I using moment.js to parse date from string with format `DD.MM.YY` to type with format `DD/MM/YY`, but it parse wrong.

Example :

```
let beginDate = "10.12.2018";
let afterPareBeginDay = moment(beginDate).format("DD/MM/YY");
```

But when parse it wrong format. Variable `afterParseBeginDay` becomes: `12/10/2018`. It's wrong. I want it must be: `10/12/2018`. I want `DD/MM/YY` but it parse to `MM/DD/YY`.

Why it was wrong?

Comment: Try `moment(beginDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

> moment(**input_date**,**input_date_format**).format(**output_date_format**);

read more here: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

```js
let beginDate = "10.12.2018";
let afterPareBeginDay = moment(beginDate,"DD.MM.YYYY").format("DD/MM/YY");
  
console.log(afterPareBeginDay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```